# Hover effect on div when hovering over anchor link outside div parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to `scale` a `div` which contains a `background image` when an `anchor` link is hovered upon.

I have seen similar questions before, [namely this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022545/hover-on-div-affects-outside-element). The solution here however, isn't ideal for me as my hover effect triggers when the anchor link is hovered upon (therefore cannot use `pointer-events`).

Essentially, when someone hovers over `.card__link`, I want to scale `.card__image`.

How do I go about this?

```css
.card__overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__image {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/01/13/01/vehicle-2275456_1280.jpg");
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.card__link:hover {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.card__link:hover ~ .card__image {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">

  <div class="card__overflow">
    <div class="card__image"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card__body">
    <div class="card__action">
      <a class="card__link" href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible using CSS with your current structure. But it is possible with JS.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code for hover should be like this in the css please check for the css changes that has been made it works like that.

```css
.card__overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card__image {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/01/13/01/vehicle-2275456_1280.jpg");
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.card__link:hover {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.card__body:hover~.card__overflow {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">

  <div class="card__body">
    <div class="card__action">
      <a class="card__link" href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card__overflow">
    <div class="card__image"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with JS.

```js
const link = document.querySelector(".card__link");
const image = document.querySelector(".card__image");

link.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  image.classList.add("scale-up")
  image.classList.remove("scale-down")
})

link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  image.classList.remove("scale-up")
  image.classList.add("scale-down")
})
```

```css
.card__overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card__image {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/01/13/01/vehicle-2275456_1280.jpg");
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.card__link:hover {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.scale-up {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.scale-down {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">

  <div class="card__overflow">
    <div class="card__image"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card__body">
    <div class="card__action">
      <a class="card__link" href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```